# components in Jdialog not shown

Tags: java, swing, components, jdialog

My application is created using Netbeans IDE (8.0.2).
I have created a JFrame which contains a JTable bound to a Database (using JPA).

I have added a "Refresh" button which is used to "refresh" the JTable data directly from the database.

I want a "Please wait" message to be displayed while data is being fetched.

For this I implemented a JDialog_PleaseWait class which extends JDialog.

For some strange reason, although the JDialog is shown the jLabel it includes does not show up...

The JDialog_PleaseWait class is :

```
 public class JDialog_PleaseWait extends javax.swing.JDialog {

//constructor for PleaseWait jDialogs

public JDialog_PleaseWait(String messageToDisplay){
    initComponents();
    this.jLabel_WaitMessage.setText(messageToDisplay);

}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel_WaitMessage = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setTitle("Please wait...");
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(227, 248, 115));
    setModalityType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
    setResizable(false);
    setType(java.awt.Window.Type.POPUP);

    jLabel_WaitMessage.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 253, 153));
    jLabel_WaitMessage.setText("WaitMessage");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel_WaitMessage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 271, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLabel_WaitMessage)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_WaitMessage;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
```

}

The refresh JButton calls a method named "reload" which initially it must display the jDialog and perform the rest of its tasks afterwards.
More specifically :

```
public void reload(){

    jTable_Activities.setEnabled(false);  // freezes the JTable

    JDialog_PleaseWait pleaseWaitDialog = new JDialog_PleaseWait("Communicating with database server...."); // create a new PleaseWait JDialog

    pleaseWaitDialog.pack();
    pleaseWaitDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this); //relative to this frame
    pleaseWaitDialog.setVisible(true);  //display the JDialog

.... ....
    // runs a DB query and updates a JTable
.... ....
```

So, for some reason the JDialog window pops up but the jLabel is not shown...

I(think I) have done the (exact?) same thing with other JDialogs which work fine but for some strange reason this JDialog does not work properly...

Any hint?

Answer (score 3):

Your likely problem is that you're fetching your data on the Swing event thread (I don't see any code above where you use Thread/Runnable/SwingWorker or the like, and hence my assumption), and that this is tying up the event thread and preventing it from doing its chores -- including drawing the label to the JDialog. The solution: do the data fetching in a background thread such as by using a SwingWorker.

Here's an example that demonstrates what I mean. The code creates two JButtons, one which displays a JDialog for 2 seconds with a `Thread.sleep(...)` running on the Swing event thread during that 2 seconds, the other with the `Thread.sleep(...)` running in a background thread. Compile and run the code to see what happens.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PleaseWaitDialogTest extends JPanel {
    protected static final long SLEEP_TIME = 2000L;

    public PleaseWaitDialogTest() {
        add(new JButton(new ShowWaitDialog("Without Thread", KeyEvent.VK_O, false)));
        add(new JButton(new ShowWaitDialog("With BG Thread", KeyEvent.VK_W, true)));
    }

    private class ShowWaitDialog extends AbstractAction {
        private boolean useBackgroundThread;
        private JDialog dialog;

        public ShowWaitDialog(String name, int mnemonic,
                boolean useBackgroundThread) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
            this.useBackgroundThread = useBackgroundThread;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // create dialog in a lazy way
            if (dialog == null) {
                Window ancestorWindow = SwingUtilities
                        .getWindowAncestor(PleaseWaitDialogTest.this);
                String title = "Dialog: " + getValue(NAME);
                dialog = new JDialog(ancestorWindow, title,
                        ModalityType.MODELESS);
                dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                dialog.add(new JLabel("Please Wait"));
                dialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            }
            dialog.setVisible(true);

            // since the dialog is non-modal, this code will run immediately after
            // the dialog has been set visible
            CloseRunnable closeRunnable = new CloseRunnable(dialog, SLEEP_TIME);
            if (useBackgroundThread) {
                // run the Runnable in a background thread
                new Thread(closeRunnable).start();
            } else {
                // run the Runnable directly on the Swing event thread
                closeRunnable.run();
            }
        }
    }

    private class CloseRunnable implements Runnable {
        protected JDialog dialog;
        private long sleepTime;

        public CloseRunnable(JDialog dialog, long sleepTime) {
            this.dialog = dialog;
            this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // the dialog *must* be closed on the Swing event thread
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (dialog != null) {
                        dialog.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        PleaseWaitDialogTest mainPanel = new PleaseWaitDialogTest();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't mind running the "reload" function within the Swing thread.To my understanding I should use a SwingWorker if the job for the "please wait" would take a lot of time, freezing the application. At (least to) this point,it's not taking a lot of time and while the popup JDialog+label appears (or at least should appear) the "reload" job has not yet started (i.e. first I try to get the JDialog+Label become visible and then run the reloading (DB query)..This is why I just placed a comment at the end of the code above ( reload() ) to show that the long taking job is being started at the end...

Comment: @TassosPan: the issue is simply this though -- if you want the dialog to paint and show its components, then the task needs to be in a background thread, something that is not that hard to do.

Comment: @TassosPan: please see posted code that demonstrates exactly what I mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I plan to do it as you advise but I would like to also have a response to my comment posted above... I.e. why is this happening...

Comment: Additionally, after running your application above, I noticed that the JDialog is not displayed properly only on the first "Without Thread" Button Press. If I click on it again it is being displayed properly all the times...